# convert multivideos from 1080p to 720p and add watermarks?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

i will ask again
i have many videos like series (dark - la casa de papel - game of thrones )
all of them without any subtitle or watermark
first i burn subtitles with handbrake
sec i use ffmpeg to burn watermark with videos by this code

for %i in ("C:\Users\shady\Downloads\convert\01*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%i" -i C:\Users\fady\Downloads\convert\shady.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" -codec:a copy "C:\Users\shady\Downloads\convert\new01%~ni.mp4"

then i convert it to 720p with this code

for %i in (C:\Users\shady\Downloads\convert\01*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -c:a copy -s hd720 "C:\Users\shady\Downloads\convert\new01%~ni.mp4"

my   question now
if i want to burn subtitle for series dark all seasons with my watermark and the final file get out with 720p with subtitle with watermark on top at right

can i do that ?

watermark png
subtitle srt
movies come with mkv not mp4 ( i want the final file come with mp4 )

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is only for questions involving Ubuntu Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the title of question - why not just add to your first command (watermark) the output size:
`-s hd720`

That saves a step right there.

For subtitles add this to command:

`subtitles=subtitle.srt`

But you may need to add filter libs or find correct build of ffmpeg. Details are explained here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo

It's not Ubuntu question though... Not exactly, but ok..

Edit: While I only now realized this was Windows + ffmpeg, here is the answer still...

**Ubuntu 20.04 (CLI) + ffmpeg**

Install ffmpeg:

```
apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

Run the `for` "batch" command:

```
for i in some-series-of-names-*.mp4; do echo ${i%%.*}; ffmpeg -i ${i%%.*}.mp4 -i some-logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,subtitles=${i%%.*}.srt" -codec:a copy -s hd720 ${i%%.*}-ubuntu.mp4; done
```

**Windows 10 + ffmpeg**

Get ffmpeg wherever. Then run command in cmd.exe:

```
for %i in (some-series-of-names-*.mp4) do echo %~ni.mp4 && ffmpeg -i %~ni.mp4 -i some-logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,subtitles=%~ni.srt" -codec:a copy -s hd720 %~ni-windows.mp4
```

**Explanation**

*bash / cmd*

`${i%%.*}` strips extension and will just use the file name string of the `i` ; in Windows cmd.exe that same function is performed by calling `%~ni`

*ffmpeg*

- `-filter_complex` can perform all kinds of overlays and such, so you
  can push both subtitle and logo through it
- `-i some-logo.png` is logo (watermark image) name
- `overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10` puts a watermark-like overlay on your screen
- `subtitles=%~ni.srt` hardcodes subtitle; subtitle has to have same name as your input mp4 file (so `movie.mp4` and `movie.srt` pairs)
- `-codec:a` copy copies audio unchanged
- `-s hd720` resizes to 720p
- `%~ni-newname.mp4` is what the output video will be named like, eg. `movie.mp4` will be named `movie-newname.mp4`

Comment: ok but for subtitle i will do it one time for all or one by one ؟ and if you have a better code for watermark and output 720hd؟

Comment: You can do everything in for loop, but you will need to feed each video its own sub. Im in a car so can't write proper script for a while. I'd name your original mp4 and srt same, eg movie.mp4 & movie.srt, start for loop, grab that %i as you already did, strip .mp4 from it, and then feed ffmpeg with `-i %i.mp4` and `subtitles=%i.srt` which will translate to something like `ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 subtitles=movie.srt` and change filenames on it's own for all mp4 files in the folder. Not sure when I can be at PC to write and test it though, probably not till 12+ hours from now

Comment: You can make it easier if subs are named `movie.mp4.srt`, then don't need to change script much, just feed ffmpeg with  subtitles=%i.srt which will translate to something like `ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 subtitles=movie.mp4.srt`

Comment: ok my friend i will try your way i hope it's work with me <3 and iam sorry for that when you have a time to write the code i will be happy for that again thanks to much for help

Comment: i try your way and this my new code

Comment: i try your way and this my new code ( 
for %i in ("C:\Users\fady\Downloads\convert\mp4withlogo\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%i" -i C:\Users\fady\Downloads\convert\Cima2u.png -filter_complex "[0]subtitles=%i.srt[v];[1][v]scale2ref=w='iw*10/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid]; [vid][wm]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" -preset fast "C:\Users\fady\Downloads\convert\mp4withlogo\New\%~ni.mp4 )

Comment: i get this error  ( Unable to parse option value "UsersfadyDownloadsconvertmp4withlogoMoney.Heist.S04E08.mp4.srt" as image size
    Last message repeated 1 times
[subtitles @ 000002d1d7d939c0] Error setting option original_size to value UsersfadyDownloadsconvertmp4withlogoMoney.Heist.S04E08.mp4.srt.
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000002d1d7d938c0] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002d1d7d95bc0] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'C:UsersfadyDownloadsconvertmp4withlogoMoney.Heist.S04E08.mp4.srt'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument )

Comment: This is ask UBUNTU, so using ffmpeg on Windows doesn't apply... But you are echoing whole path there instead just file name

Comment: Opps iam so sorry i didn't see thie ubuntu :( ..... i using ffmpeg on windows ... So you have a solution to the problem ? :(

Comment: posted full answer ... please mark as answer if you've found it to work

Comment: thanksyou man tooo much it's working very good <3

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: hi my friend how are yo ? i hope every thing okay with you :) i try your way for 8 days now it's a great code really but i have one problem the output files come with high size some time how can i make it come with less size :)

Comment: Sorry, I am not ffmpeg expert, but good quality with acceptable size needs a lot of tweaking depending on your personal preferences. You can try some presents, and see if their size/quality look good or not. Also, processing strength and encoding time will probably matter for you as well. You should probably read this ( Choose a preset and tune ): https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 Pick some of the presets, try `slow` or `slower` or `veryslow` and see if any fit your needs